# Serial communication between stm32f103 and computer using USB to ttl pl2303

Tags: usbserial, usart

I would like to know is if is possible to send data from my stm32f103 board to my laptop using usb-ttl pl2303. I have tried but even after downloading the drivers the com port is not recognized by com terminal applications.

Comment: What OS do you have?

Comment: i am using windows 8

Comment: Is not it supposed to find the driver by itself?

Comment: no, i downloaded some drivers from the producers but i think the drivers are strictly for company product not china counterfeits

Comment: This is a Windows/Driver problem. However once that is sorted make sure you set the voltage levels correctly. 3V3 I would suspect on yo stm32f103 board.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

i think i found the solution, for others who might be in need, u have to backdate or roll back the driver .you do that by downloading old driver packages .